# Jenkins to automate deb reprepro repository creation/signing

Tags: jenkins, debian, gnupg, sign, deb

Problem statement:

- Can sign repos from inside normal terminal (also inside docker). From jenkins job, repo creation/signing fails. Job hangs.

Configuration:

- Jenkins spawns docker container to create/sign deb repository.
- Private and public keys all present.
- gpg-agent installed on the docker container to sign the packages.
- ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf file has "use-agent" enabled

Progress:

- Can start gpg-agent using jenkins on the docker container.
- Can use gpg-preset-passphrase to cache passphrase.
- Can use [OUTSIDE JENKINS]

  ```
  reprepro --ask-passphrase -Vb .  includedeb ${_repo_name} ${_pkg_location}
  ```

  to fetch the passphrase from gpg-agent and sign the repo.

Problem:

- from inside a jenkins job, the command  "reprepro --ask-passphrase -Vb ..." hangs.

Code:

- starting gpg-agent:

  ```
  GPGAGENT=/usr/bin/gpg-agent
  GNUPG_PID_FILE=${GNUPGHOME}/gpg-agent-info
  GNUPG_CFG=${GNUPGHOME}/gpg.conf
  GNUPG_CFG=${GNUPGHOME}/gpg-agent.conf

  function start_gpg_agent {
      GPG_TTY=$(tty) 
      export GPG_TTY 
      if [ -r "${GNUPG_PID_FILE}" ]
      then
          source "${GNUPG_PID_FILE}" count=$(ps lax | grep "${GPGAGENT}" | grep "$SSH_AGENT_PID" | wc -l)
          if [ $count -eq 0 ] 
          then 
              if ! ${GPGAGENT} 2>/dev/null then 
                  $GPGAGENT --debug-all --options ${BASE_PATH}/sign/gpg-agent.options \
                   --daemon  --enable-ssh-support \
                   --allow-preset-passphrase --write-env-file ${GNUPG_PID_FILE}

              if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] 
              then 
                  echo "INFO::agent started" 
              else 
                  echo "INFO::Agent could not be started. Exit." 
                  exit -101 
              fi 
          fi 
      fi 
      else
          $GPGAGENT --debug-all --options ${BASE_PATH}/sign/gpg-agent.options \
          --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase --write-env-file ${GNUPG_PID_FILE}
      fi 
  }
  ```
- options file:

  ```
  default-cache-ttl 31536000
  default-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
  max-cache-ttl 31536000
  max-cache-ttl-ssh 31536000
  enable-ssh-support 
  debug-all
  ```
- saving passphrase.

  ```
  /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -v --preset --passphrase ${_passphrase} ${_fp}
  ```
- finally (for completion), sign repo:

  ```
  reprepro --ask-passphrase -Vb .  includedeb ${_repo_name} ${_pkg_location}
  ```